# Changing text of done button in keyboard in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, keyboard, uitextfield

I want to change its text to 'Save'.

I guess I need create a custom keyboard to do it. But should I create all keyboard buttons from scratch or there is a way to customize only 'Done' button?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806750/changing-text-of-done-button-in-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

`returnKeyType` a property on the textfield, see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType) for `returnKeyType` and its available constant values:

```
UIReturnKeyDefault,
UIReturnKeyGo,
UIReturnKeyGoogle,
UIReturnKeyJoin,
UIReturnKeyNext,
UIReturnKeyRoute,
UIReturnKeySearch,
UIReturnKeySend,
UIReturnKeyYahoo,
UIReturnKeyDone,
UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall
```