# Localization of UItextfied Keyboad returnkeyType text

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uitextfield, return-type

I have a text field which has the `returnKeyType` as `.join`. Now the issue is when I use the app for the French language (means using by changing the language of the app) it does not change in localized language rather than it shows the return icon. But I need to "join" text to translate in the localized language. Please suggest.

In English:
[image]

In French:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806750/changing-text-of-done-button-in-keyboard

Comment: @Mocha My question is related to localization of returnType key? isn't it? How comes it a duplicate?

Comment: That is why I said _Possible_ . The question description asks to change the key due to localization. The first answer in that post says that we cannot set it to a custom text, only the enums. Also, the enum value for .join should be localized with the phone's language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing text of done button in keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806750/changing-text-of-done-button-in-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

Click on Setting ---> General ---> Keyboard --> Keyboards ---> Add New keyboards
You can add key boards for your different language.
Then change the keyboard by click the bellow button. [image]

Please refer my screensort for arabic test.
[image]
It may helps you. Thank you.

Comment: Changing this also does not change the text translation then it will show the return icon.